# i have a code that its kinda dirty and i cant think of a way to improve it, what can i do to have a more compact and better solution?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, e-commerce

I'm trying to get a specific result of my database in mongoose, but this is what i have its working but the code looks pretty bad.

```
 const completedOrders = await Order.find({ "status": "delivered" }).
    populate('address');
```

the response of the database is this and i trying to get all the states of every order with status: "delivered"

```
"completedOrders": [
    {
        "_id": "61b81eef631dcc413e98515a",
        "user": "61b51dcbfd50717dc6dc931a",
        "address": {
            "address": {
                "phone": 54156345645768,
                "rut": "26.232.966-6",
                "state": "metropolitana",
                "city": "dunno",
                "province": "pepe",
                "street": "asdaqqqqqqqda",
                "numstreet": 999
            },
            "_id": "61b8179e7dfc15f26c561175",
            "user": "61b51dcbfd50717dc6dc931a",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "status": "delivered",
        "orderItems": [
            "61b81ee6631dcc413e985146",
            "61b81ee6631dcc413e985147"
        ],
        "shipping": 3500,
        "code": "c986aeb3-1fc9-422e-8638-b40651d7906c",
        "total": 690,
        "totalCost": 370,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-14T04:34:55.564Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-12-14T04:34:55.564Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "61b81fddda2eb87de7d44c42",
        "user": "61b51dcbfd50717dc6dc931a",
        "address": {
            "address": {
                "phone": 54156345645768,
                "rut": "26.232.966-6",
                "state": "metropolitana",
                "city": "dunno",
                "province": "pepe",
                "street": "asdaqqqqqqqda",
                "numstreet": 999
            },
            "_id": "61b8179e7dfc15f26c561175",
            "user": "61b51dcbfd50717dc6dc931a",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "status": "delivered",
        "orderItems": [
            "61b81fdbda2eb87de7d44c32",
            "61b81fdbda2eb87de7d44c33"
        ],
        "shipping": 3500,
        "code": "e2828a65-ea12-43e9-9909-f081c9cd32e9",
        "total": 690,
        "totalCost": 370,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-14T04:38:53.517Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-12-14T04:38:53.517Z"
    }
]
```

so this is what i tried but its quite dirty and i still want to do the same for city, and provinces, is for the analitycs of my ecommerce

```
    const AddressesUser = await Promise.all(completedOrders.map(async (array) => {
        const allAddresses = array.address;
        return allAddresses;
    }));

    const arrayAddresses = await Promise.all(AddressesUser.map(async (array) => {
        const allAddresses = array.address;
        return allAddresses;
    }));

    
    const allStates = await Promise.all(arrayAddresses.map(async (array) => {
        const states = array.state;
        return states;
    }));
```

Comment: To start with, there is no reason to use promises with any of your three `.map()` functions in the last code block.  None of those operations are asynchronous so using promises is just wasteful.  Just use regular `.map()`.

Comment: If you're going to build all three arrays, then you may as well just iterate the array of objects once and collect all three arrays at once rather than do three separate iterations of the data.

Comment: @jfriend00 for some reason if i dont use promises all my values come empty, and about the iterations i must be an idiot, i dont know why i didnt think that before, i just started in nodejs....

Comment: Promises are ONLY for managing asynchronous operations.  I don't see any asynchronous operations in your `.map()`.  Please show a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Since this is only plain Javascript, you should even be able to demonstrate it in a code snippet built into your question.  I suspect you just weren't using `.map()` correctly somehow.

Comment: You can possibly avoid the array operations. Write an [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation/) query with appropriate projections (and/or other operations) to get the desired results. Also, it is not clear what the expected output is.

Comment: @jfriend00 i fix the problem with promises all, thanks for telling me about that, the reason why it wasnt working before is because i was putting an async in another part of the code, i didnt pass the whole code in the question cause it was way to much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation, if you want the state field at top level:

```
[{"$match":{"status":"delivered"}},{"$addFields":{"state":"$address.address.state"}},{"$project":{"state":1,"status":1}}]
```

If you want any other parameter, you just have to add it in the project stage.

If you only want the state key, this aggregation flow will also be helpful:

```
[{"$match":{"status":"delivered"}},{"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":{"state":"$address.address.state"}}}]
```

This will replace the root, and all keys will be removed which are present above that level.

Comment: Your answer is quite interesting i didnt know about that method for mongoose, but unfortunate doesnt work, cause if i use that method i wont be able to use populate to bring the address, even though thanks!!

Comment: to populate the address you can use lookup stage of aggregation.

```[{"$match": { "status": "delivered"}},{"$lookup": {"from": "address", "localField": "address",  "foreignField": "_id", "as": "address" }},{"$unwind": { "path": "$address", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true }}]```

to get fields you want you can use project for filtering

Comment: explanation for what the fields are doing for easier reference

`lookup.from -> add your collection name which is storing address`

 `lookup.localField-> the key in users who is having reference to address model`

 `lookup.foreignField-> address foreign key`

  `lookup.as ->  the key in which you want the result`

   `unwind -> this will convert address array into object`

  ` preserveNullAndEmptyArrays->this will tells to keep the object or not who have address as empty`